# How to get parameters after # sign in aiohttp

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7, aiohttp

My server is getting request from url like

http://127.0.0.1:8050/get_request#a=ABCD&b=EFG

but `request.rel_url` returns only `/get_request`

How do I get part after `#`?

Comment: Fragments are used by the browser only, they aren't even sent to the server (this is why you don't see it on server side, `/get_request` is correct). I guess it's somehow misleading that `aiohttp` mentions the fragment in the request docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looks like only js can read that. I'm coding js first time, but that is what I came up with:

( that page is being opened with browser)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.URL.indexOf("#") != -1)
{
    var this_url = document.URL.replace("#", "?");
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', this_url);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-url');
    request.send(); 
}
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```